# given input prefix, get suffix in python re

Tags: python, regex, prefix, suffix

I have a function that takes in a string and a prefix word. I want to use re.findall to get a list of suffix words that follow the given prefix.
For example:

```
string: "My mother gave my sister my robot." 
prefix: "my"
result: ["mother", "sister", "robot"]
```

My implementation is

```
def suffix(txt, prefix):
    rv = re.findall(prefix + r' \w{4-15}',txt)
    rv = [i.replace(prefix,'') for i in rv]
    return rv
```

However, I am getting [] returned. 
Can someone suggest how I can implement this, using re?

Comment: Try `{4,15}` instead of `{4-15}`.

Answer (score 2):

Building on top of other answers here is a 1 liner

```
>>> s = "My mother gave my sister my robot."
>>> import re
>>> prefix = "my"
>>> re.findall(prefix + r'\s+(\w+)', s, re.IGNORECASE)
['mother', 'sister', 'robot']
>>>
```

Comment: I think you might need `\s+`, otherwise it might get a hit on (for example) "mystify" (although the question is a little ambiguous).

Answer (score 1):

Several issues here, first the range separator inside a quantifier is a comma not a hyphen, so: `{4,15}` instead of `{4-15}`.

Second, you need to match both `my` and `My`, so the match should be case insensitive (`re.IGNORECASE`).

Third, if you use a *capturing parentheses group* (the round brackets) with `finditer` then you don't need to hack off the prefix.

Try this:

```
import re

def suffix(txt, prefix):
    rv = []
    for m in re.finditer(prefix + r' (\w{4,15})', txt, re.IGNORECASE):
        rv.append(m.groups()[0])

    return rv

print suffix("My mother gave my sister my robot.", "my")
```

Gives:

```
['mother', 'sister', 'robot']
```

Depending on needs, `\b` (word boundary) might be better than a space to separate words.  For example:  "my, and your, stuff" would not match using a space.

Answer (score 0):

Since @cdarke covered your main issues with your problem, another way would be to split `string` into a list of words with [`re.sub()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub), and if a word in the list is equal to any case of `prefix`, get the previous word and add it to your resulting list.

Here is an example:

```
import re

string = "My mother gave my sister my robot."
prefix = "my"

words = re.sub("[^\w]", " ",  string).split()

suffixes = [words[i] for i in range(len(words)) if words[i-1].lower() == prefix]

print(suffixes)
```

Which Outputs:

```
['mother', 'sister', 'robot']
```

**Note:** In order to check if any case in the words list match with `prefix`, you can convert it to lowercase first with `lower()`.

Answer (score 0):

That's where you need   Positive Lookbehind :

Here we go:

```
import re

def find_suffix(word,string):
    pattern = '(?<=' + word + '\s)\w+'
    return re.findall(pattern,string)
print(find_suffix('my',"my mother gave my sister my robot."))
```

output:

```
['mother', 'sister', 'robot']
```